# VB.NET Difference between Focus() and BringToFront()

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I'm developing an application in WinForms and I have 2 MDI children and I'd like to know the difference between Form.Focus and Form.BringToFront

I would like to know which one to use when clicking on a respective form's titlebar in order to have it pop up while I'm drag/dropping the form

If you are setting the child form mdiParent property after you are calling Form.Show then it messes up the focus of all the child forms so for me, drag/drop of MDI children inside an MDI parent won't focus the form upon Drag start, but only after MouseUp

Comment: When I click and hold on a MDI child's titlebar, it automatically brings to form on top. I do not have to wait for mouse up?

Comment: ron I clarified the issue in my question

Comment: Have you tried setting the Child's MDIParent before calling Form.Show()?

Comment: as far as I can tell by looking at the placement of each .MDIParent it's before any .Show :\ however another reason might be because I'm programmatically creating Forms that they don't comply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I open MDI Child Forms, I create the following function within the MDI Parent:

```
Public Sub ShowMDIChild(f As Form)
    f.MdiParent = Me
    f.Show()
End Sub
```

The "f" argument is the new form I wish to open:

```
MyMDIPParent.ShowMDIChild(New Hospitals)
```

Comment: I was generating a new form using a With block to assign all the variables and even though .MdiParent was before .Show it didn't work. Once I put .MdiParent out and above the With block, everything worked perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

Focus() sets focus to U element.
BringToFront() brings your element on top of other elements (which overlap your element).

So if you use BringToFront() on your form, it will be brought to front over over windows in your MDI environment. But it doesn't mean that your form will gain focus.
If you use Focus(), your form will gain focus: for example you will be able to interact with the form via keyboard. But it does not mean that form will be brought to front over other forms.
So maybe you should use both methods.

Comment: thanks Dima, however I'm already clicking the titlebar to drag so it will assume focus on MouseUp, so it would seem .Focus contains .BringToFront because they both do the same thing for me.